# Trying to create/associate functions dynamically to variables in a for loop

Tags: python, function, dictionary, for-loop, variables

My code reads from a csv the parameters to create an object (in that case a bus, a common element in the power system) and associate every object to a variable. I'm trying my code to create as many buses as rows are inside the csv file (the columns are the parameters of each bus) using a for loop and i think i have achieved that as the variables bus0 bus1 bus2 and so on are created and the data frames with the parameters readed in the csv are also there and are accessible.

But when I try to use such variables (bus0, bus1...) to do other things (e.g. attach a generation point to bus0) it keeps saying that "bus0 doesn't exists" even though i see it on my variable window. I tried many things but doesn't look it works, would appreciate any help thanks. i attach a fragment of my code below:

```
    import pandapower as pp
    import csv

    net = pp.create_empty_network() #create an empty network


    with open('Bus_data_test.csv', 'r') as Bus_data:
         BD = [row for row in csv.reader(Bus_data)]
    print(BD)

    Buses={}

    i=0
    for rows in BD:

        Buses["Bus{0}".format(i)]= pp.create_bus (net, vn_kv=float(BD[i][0]), name=BD[i][1], index=int(i), geodata=None, type=str(BD[i][4]), zone=int(BD[i][5]), in_service=bool(BD[i][6]), max_vm_pu=float(BD[i][7]), min_vm_pu=float(BD[i][8]), coords=BD[i][9])
i=i+1
   print(net.bus)
   print(net.bus.iat[0,5])

    with open('Gen_data.csv', 'r') as Gen_data:
        GD = [row for row in csv.reader(Gen_data)]

    print(GD)  

    Generators={}

     i=0
    for rows in GD:

       Generators["Gen{0}".format(i)] = pp.create_gen(net, GD[i][0], p_mw=GD[i][1], vm_pu=GD[i][2], name=GD[i][3], index=int(i), max_q_mvar=GD[i][7], min_q_mvar=GD[i][8], min_p_mw=GD[i][6], max_p_mw=GD[i][5], scaling=GD[i][9], type=str(GD[i][10]), slack=bool(GD[i][11]), controllable=GD[i][12], in_service=GD[i][13])
       i=i+1
    print(net.gen)
```

And here a fragment of the csv:

```
Bus0,230,Bus0,0,None,b,1,True,1.1,0.9,None,bus0,50,30.99,0,0,None,1.0,0,True
Bus1,230,Bus1,1,None,b,1,True,1.1,0.9,None,bus1,170,105.35,0,0,None,1.0,1,True
```

The traceback error:

```
C:\Users...lib\site-packages\pandapower\create.py:1177: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  if bus not in net["bus"].index.values:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-e022521b4210>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users...Net_reader_test.py', wdir='C:/Users/...Matpower')

  File "C:\Users\...lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/...Net_reader_test.py", line 41, in <module>
    Generators["Gen{0}".format(i)] = pp.create_gen(net, GD[i][0], p_mw=GD[i][1], vm_pu=GD[i][2], name=GD[i][3], index=int(i), max_q_mvar=GD[i][7], min_q_mvar=GD[i][8], min_p_mw=GD[i][6], max_p_mw=GD[i][5], scaling=GD[i][9], type=str(GD[i][10]), slack=bool(GD[i][11]), controllable=GD[i][12], in_service=GD[i][13])

  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\pandapower\create.py", line 1178, in create_gen
    raise UserWarning("Cannot attach to bus %s, bus does not exist" % bus)

UserWarning: Cannot attach to bus Bus0, bus does not exist
```

Comment: Please update your question with examples of your use of variables that should exist, along with the full error traceback you get.

Comment: Are you saying that you try to do `Buses["Bus0"]` somewhere and get a `KeyError: Bus0` error? Or maybe trying to use a variable named `bus0` and get `NameError: name 'bus0' is not defined`? Your buses are in a dict so the second method isn't right, and you are adding as "Bus0" etc... (big B) so "bus0" isn't right.

Comment: Posting the traceback message so we can see the failing line and exact error message would help.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, im trying the second one and getting not defined. Also tried to do it like this: 

Buses=['Bus0','Bus1','Bus2','Bus3']
i=0
for rows in BD:
    
  vars()[Buses[i]]= pp.create_bus (net, vn_kv=float(BD[i][1]), name=BD[i][2], index=int(i), geodata=None, type=str(BD[i][5]), zone=int(BD[i][6]), in_service=bool(BD[i][7]), max_vm_pu=float(BD[i][8]), min_vm_pu=float(BD[i][9]), coords=BD[i][10], )
  i=i+1

using vars() to force Bus0, Bus1... to be created, and they appeared to the variable explorer but again not usable "Bus0 doesn't exist". Thanks

Comment: You created a dictionary that holds key/value pairs, but that doesn't create like named variables. Although you can create variables called `bus0`, `bus1` etc... that's not a normal thing to do. Dynamically generated variables tend to be useless because you usually end up with extra code to dynamcially regenerate the names and fetch them. `Buses` already has "Bus0", etc... Just use it.

Comment: But when i try to attach the generation to the bus0 (readed from csv position GD[i][1])  
`Generators["Gen{0}".format(i)] = pp.create_gen(net, **GD[i][0]**, p_mw=GD[i][1], vm_pu=GD[i][2])`  
i need this bus0 to be an existing variable for this to work, im so noob at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create variables named after the keys in `Buses`. This is not a common thing to do, but here is an example. I cleaned up `Buses` creation a bit and left out the other code to just focus on this one problem.

```
import pandapower as pp
import csv

net = pp.create_empty_network() #create an empty network

Buses = {}
with open('Bus_data_test.csv', 'r') as Bus_data:
    for index, row in enumerate(csv.reader(Bus_data)):
        Buses["Bus{0}".format(index)] = pp.create_bus(net,
            vn_kv=float(row[0]), name=row[1], index=index, 
            geodata=None, type=row[4], zone=int(row[5]),
            in_service=(row[6]=="True"), max_vm_pu=float(row[7]),
            min_vm_pu=float(row[8]), coords=row[9])

assert len(Buses) > 0

# normally one would just use the name in the dict
print(Buses["Bus0"])

# but module level variables can be constructed
for name,value in Buses.items():
    globals()[name.lower()] = value
print(bus0)
```

Comment: it worked, thank you sir! Just for me to understand what you did:  
- in the first part (for index, row...) you use enumerate to allocate the row number as index? is that correct?  
- After that, you make sure with assert that the dictionary have at least 1 element?  
- Then you force the buses dict items name and value to be variable name and variable value?  (you use lower() to make sure the name is in lowecase or why?)  
Thank you again!

Comment: Yes to all, and since you said _when I try to use such variables (bus0, bus1...)_, and those are lower case, so I changed them. There is no reason for the lower except to match your question.

Comment: I'm not sure what the traceback you posted means - I don't know pandapower - but I suspect that my demonstration about global variables won't fix it.

Comment: It did! Or at least it only appears a different message (much shorter):  
runfile('C:/Users/.../NetReader_SO_test.py', wdir='C:/Users/.../Matpower')
C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\pandapower\io_utils.py:8: FutureWarning: pandas.util.testing is deprecated. Use the functions in the public API at pandas.testing instead.
  from pandas.util.testing import assert_series_equal, assert_frame_equal

Comment: Glad to hear it. This new messsage says you are using old functions from `pandas.util.testing` and should move to new ones in `pandas.testing`. It could be that `pandapower` is using them and its the one that should be updated. If so, it would be worth seeing if its package maintainer knows about the warning.